# Find the equation of the line with sum of intercepts is 5 and slope is 3

Tags: analytic-geometry, slope

I am having  trouble finding a formula that connects the two and can produce an answer. Anyone know how this is done? I tried y=mx+b, m=3, and b=5-a. But I don't know what to do next or did I even start right.

Comment: When does a line produce its $x$-intercept?

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, consider *accepting* the best answer and upvoting all useful answers you got. That's how the site works.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the intercept form of a line.
Assume $x$-intercept to be $a$ and $y$-intercept to be $b$. Then equation of line is given by

$$\frac xa+\frac yb=1.$$
Which implies $$bx+ay=ab$$

So slope of line is:  $-\frac ba=3$

Also, you have-
$$a+b=5.$$
All that remains is to solve these two equations.

Comment: It might be useful to explain to the OP what "the slope-intercept form of a line" is. The OP might not use the same terminology and be confused by your answer...

Comment: Fair enough, I did so. Also changed my original terminology to avoid confusion. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Great! Notice I edited your answer a little more, mainly to make it easier to read and to improve the way it looks. Please review the fixes carefully and follow try to keep them in mind next time you are answering. In particular, write all variables in math mode, not italics. So don't write `*a*` (which produces *a*), but rather `$a$` (which produces $a$). Also, write entire mathematical expressions, not just individual symbols, in math mode. Write `$a=\frac{1}{x}$` (which yields "$a=\frac{1}{x}$") instead of `a=$\frac{1}{x}$` which yields a much uglier "a=$\frac{1}{x}$"

Comment: Ah, I understand. Thanks, still figuring MathJax out, only joined 2-3 days ago.

Comment: Not a problem at all, we all learn by doing. I really suggest you review the edit I made, it makes the post cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: Certainly will do.

Answer (score 1):

The slope is $3$ so $y = 3x + b$. The intercepts are found when $x = 0$ or $y = 0$, so when $x = 0, y = b$, and when $y = 0, 0 = 3x + b \implies x = -b/3$. Hence $b + (-b/3) = 5$ and you can continue from here.